# Select a random sample within levels of a factor, unequal stratum size per factor level

Tags: r, random, dplyr, sample

I would like to select a random sample of my dataframe within levels of a factor.  I can get a sample within the factor levels using ddply:

```
library(dplyr)
newdf <- ddply(iris, ~Species, function(x){
  ndf <- x[sample(nrow(x),2), ]
})
with(newdf,table(Species))
```

However, I don't want to simply sample 2 observations from each factor level. Rather, I want to sample, say 2,3 and 4 observations from within the 3 levels of Species (i.e. 2 from setosa, 3 from versicolor, 4 frm virginica). How can I do this?

Can I create a vector of values, e.g. c(2,3,4) to be cycled through with each dataframe split by ddply?

The values in that vector need to be specified - they are not a consistent proportion of all data, nor are they a consistent number.

Comment: You mean "**stratified sample with unequal strata**"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We `split` the dataset by the 'Species', use `Map` to `sample` the number of observations, and `rbind` the `list` output.

```
 do.call(rbind, Map(function(x,y) x[sample(y),], split(iris, iris$Species), 2:4))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. That has worked beautifully.  For those who don't immediately see it (like I wouldn't have a few weeks back), the 2:4 at the end can be substituted with a named vector of sample sizes.